# How to set up "localhost" document root as Mac's "Sites" folder with MAMP PRO 4?

Tags: permission, apache, mamp

The default MAMP's localhost document root is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` and I want to point it on my `/Users/Me/Sites/` folder.

I can do easily with MAMP PRO GUI but it's not working after I restarted servers and it's showing me a red arrow (as an invalid destination):

[image]

I tried some solutions like:

- Change default Apache port to 8888
- Change default web user to me
- Do an alias from MAMP *htdocs* folder to *Sites* folder
- Do a symbolic link from MAMP *htdocs* folder to *Sites* folder
- Try to set *Sites* folder owner (only) to me and group to *Sites* (but doesn't seem not work)
- Set *Sites* permissions to 777, 755 and 750
- Add an *index.php* file inside
- Creating a new host

But MAMP still doesn't accept my *Sites* folder as document root!
I tried with websites sub-folders inside *Sites* or with other Mac's personal folders like *Music*, *Pictures*, *Downloads* or my own home and they are working! Only *Documents* or *Desktop* folders don't work either.

It's seems a permission issue, but I don't know how to resolve it. Does it because *Sites* folder is used by other macOS apps or services?

**Edit (27/07/2017):** I opened an issue on official MAMP bugtracker: http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=5945

**Edit 2 (10/01/2018):** From an official MAMP bugtracker administrator: "`~/Sites` will be allowed starting v4.3." (adb - 04.12.2017)

**Edit 3 (07/02/2018):** New MAMP v4.3 (released 24/01/2018) allows "~/Sites" as localhost root folder, watch [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314726/121854) below.

Comment: This seems to be a cosmetic problem. Copying index.php and the png to the Sites folder and starting the server simply works here (though an invalid dir is indicated in MAMP PRO).

Comment: Not only "cosmetic", because Apache or Nginx warnings are displayed each time servers are (re)started: "Some hosts have invalid disk location…"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localhost root folder to "~/Sites" is now allowed (from MAMP v4.3):

[image: MAMP PRO v4.3 allows "~/Sites" localhost root folder]